# EJS page not rendering /redirecting after req.getValidationResult() method

Tags: node.js, ajax, ejs

Ajax request has the following code:

```
function validate_referral(e){
    // stop default action
  e.preventDefault();

    const  button = this.children[this.children.length-1];
    //Form Handling with ajax

    $.ajax({
        url      : '/validatereferral',
        method   : 'GET',
        data     :  $(this).serialize(),
        dataType :  'json',

     beforeSend : function(http){
            button.style.opacity = '0.7';
            button.innerText = 'Submitting';
            button.setAttribute("disabled", "true");
        },
    });
}
```

Now i am validating in the DB if the code exists and if so i would like to render/redirect to a different web page. But render/redirection is failing. Any help is much appreciated.

```
router.get('/validatereferral',function(req,res){
    var referralCode = req.body.referralcode;
    if(referralCode == ""){
        data = {msg:"Referral Code is required.",param:"",success:false};
    }else {
        var validation = req.checkBody('referralcode', 'Referral code already exist. Please enter a unique code').isExist_referralcodegen();
            req.getValidationResult()
            .then(function(result) {
                var error = result.array();
                var data;
                if (!(error.length == 0)) {
                    data = {msg: "This is an invalid referral code.", success: false};
                    res.send(data);
                }
                console.log("validgen");
                //res.redirect("http://localhost:3000/signup")
                res.render('signup',{title:"Community Network | Sign Up",header:false,navbar:false});
            })
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are sending an AJAX request. In AJAX response, redirect or render will not be reflected on your website. Instead your server should response the url and client have to change browser url.

```
$.ajax({
    url      : '/validatereferral',
    method   : 'GET',
    data     :  $(this).serialize(),
    dataType :  'json',
    beforeSend : function(http){
        button.style.opacity = '0.7';
        button.innerText = 'Submitting';
        button.setAttribute("disabled", "true");
    },
}).done(function(data) { 
  location.href = data;
});
```

In server,

```
res.send("http://localhost:3000/signup")
```